# Wordpress post filter by Ajax with Multi selection checkboxes and radio button without submit

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress, filter

I am working on wordpress theme development. One of this section I need to filter posts as like my project Hotels by following attachment image. I need to filter Hotel by price, types, star rating and more. I need this filter without submit button. Just clicking any fields user showing live changes Hotel list. Please see my attachment image. You can understand what I need. Please help me with source code. I am not expert on ajax filtering into wordpress. Thank you.
[image]

Comment: just add return false; after all the events you want fired

Comment: What source code do you have so far?

Comment: do you need help with the js part of the ajax request or the php part?

Comment: both of js and php